# Printing JSON object in EJS with NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, ejs

I have a nodejs website where I want to console.log data on the frontend. I make an API request and get back JSON code. I want to display specific data from this code on the front end with EJS. I am sending code like this:

```js
  got.get(q, {responseType: 'json'})
  .then(d => {
    const info = d.body;
    console.log(info.flightTracks[0].flightId)
    var x = JSON.stringify(info)
    console.log(x)
    res.render('flight', {
        info: x
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err.message);
  });
```

Q is the API URL. In my EJS, I am doing console.log(<%- info %>) to print out my data which works and prints the object. But if I try console.log(<%- info.request %>) which is a valid query it prints nothing. Please help!

The results from the API are:

```json
{
request: {
airline: {
requested: "AA",
interpreted: "AA"
},
hourOfDay: {
interpreted: 0
},
flight: {
requested: "100",
interpreted: "100"
},
utc: {
requested: "true",
interpreted: true
},
includeFlightPlan: {
interpreted: false
},
numHours: {
interpreted: 24
},
url: "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/flight/tracks/AA/100/dep/2021/6/24?utc=true",
date: {
year: "2021",
month: "6",
day: "24",
interpreted: "2021-06-24"
}
},
```

There is a lot more data which I cant give here.

Comment: Can you share the expected results form query in the question code?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I did something like this:
var x = <%- info %>;

Comment: But VS Code gives an error with this. This works and prints the data but how can I get rid of the VS Code error?

Comment: what is the error? Can you add it?

Comment: So your problem is with VSCode highlighter? :)

Comment: Remove this line `var x = JSON.stringify(info)`, you don't need to convert `x` to a string. `res.render('flight', { info });`